# Object not being destroyed when shot with a bullet - UNITY3D C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So in my game, there's a gun that sprays bullets, and I'm trying to make a gameObject destroy on collision with the bullets. The bullets are based off of one gameObject (Capsule). I've tried these two scripts so far:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class whenshot : MonoBehaviour {

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.name == "Bullet")
    {
        Destroy(col.gameObject);
    }
}
}
```

and:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class whenshot : MonoBehaviour {


void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.name == "Bullet")
    {
        Destroy(this); //the difference between the two is that I changed "col.gameObject" to "this"
    }
}
}
```

I'm shooting the object but it's not disappearing/destroying itself. How can I fix this?

Here's a visual if it helps: [image: Visual]

Comment: It appears that your original code was destroying the bullet, not the object it hit.

Comment: Add the following lines of code to the top of the function and tell us what it shows you in the log when you try it again `Debug.Log("name: " + col.gameObject.name);`, `Debug.Log("matches: " + (col.gameObject.name == "Bullet").ToString());`, if you don't get any log messages tell us that too.

Comment: @SCottChamberlain if the log is under the console, then I didn't get any log messages.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain is there anything I should do with colliders or rigidbodies?

Comment: If you got no messages in the console your code is not being run. Next I would creaet a function for `Awake` and see if a message gets logged there. If no message then `whenshot` is not being put on your object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I figured it out, it's kind of weird but apparently I was making the bullets move too fast... I had to slow down the "Bullet_Forward_Force" float to about 150f to make it work. Thanks to everyone who answered though.

Answer (score 4):

`this` refers to the object instance of the caller ([this is basic OOP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz.aspx)), i.e., `whenshot`, and not `gameObject`. So the second sample is effectively `Destroy`ing the instance of the script from the `gameObject` it is attached to.

The first script is technically fine, and should work, provided these conditions are met:

1. Either the projectile (bullet) or the target (or both) have a non-kinematic rigidbody component attached. ([Unity docs.](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter.html))
2. Both have 3D Collider components.
3. The name of **every single** bullet gameObject that collides with the target is **exactly** "Bullet".
4. All projectile objects have this script as a component.

**Some suggestions**

Use prefabs and tags: take your bullet primitive and store it as a prefab. Add a tag to the prefab called "Bullet". Do the same for the target and tag it as "Target". Tag the player as "Player". In the "gunController", set a reference to the bullet prefab and make it Instantiate bullets on whatever trigger you're using. In the **bullet**'s script, use `CompareTag("Target")` instead of `==` and Destroy both the target gameObject and this.gameObject.

It seems to me that the above is the behaviour you want. If that is the case, there is no delay between collision and destruction, and hence no need to simulate physics whatsoever. Unless you have some other physics interactions with bullets/targets, mark the one without a rigidbody as a Trigger.

**A Strong Suggestion**

Go through Unity tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example from a 2D Game I made a while back, but i think it might help.

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.tag == "Destroyable")
    {
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
    }
}
```

I used this to destroy certain blocks when the player would shoot them so many times, just switch them to the 3D Collider and Trigger, but it should do the trick for ya (i hope ^^).

edit: this script should be attached to your bullet prefab

Comment: Didn't work, I could've done the code wrong, here it is:     


void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
       

        if (other.tag == "Bullet")
        {
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
        }
    }
}

Do I have to do anything with Colliders or triggers?

Comment: looks like that code will destroy the bullet, you would also have to destroy the target object you're shooting at. Tag that block with "Enemy" or something, and try destroying them both on Collision

Comment: Can you provide me with another code to do that? Sorry I started Unity like 3 days ago so I'm pretty new.

Comment: it's kind of hard to explain due to the different ways of setting up the environment and attaching scripts to object prefabs, if you want drop your Steam Profile or some messenger contact and i can work with you on it.

Comment: Can I give my steam profile to you tomorrow? I'm watching the Chile game right now and then I'm going to bed.

Comment: sure just inbox me whenever

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so I will make an answer:

You can make the bullet go fast, just set the collision detection to continious dynamic.

It has an almost %100 success rate.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that when I can.